# Website database access from android application

Tags: android, webforms, return-value

I am doing a freelance android project which requires telephone no. operator name from a website. My application will send the telephone no to the website. This is fine, I can do it by requesting a customized URL from the app. But in return how I can get the operator name in my application?

When I enter phone no. in the website it shows a webpage with the operator name.

Here is the phone no. [website address](https://nummertjanster.pts.se/net/sv/Nummerkapacitet/Enskiltnummer):

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract it from the input stream returned by URL.getContent();

For a single information like this regexp pattern matching is best, otherwise you should use a library that handles html parsing such as tagsoup (part of android distro) or my favorite : [apache jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html). (Although it can be tough to compile it for android)

Comment: would you please point to regex pattern matching I have no knowledge on that

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the response you get via URL.getContent(). In the best case, you can use a standard response format like XML or JSON. In the worsed case you have to parse HTML (which you don't want to, believe me).

Comment: Definitely don't want to parse html!